# Replacing non-ASCII characters

Tags: c#, strings, regex, memory-management, xml

I wrote a C# program to remove non-ASCII characters in a text file, and then output the result to a `.NonAsciiChars` file.

The input file is in XML format. In fact, the data may all be on two lines, which is why I am not doing the replacement line by line. Instead, I'm using `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`.

The problem is, the input file can be as big as 4 GB. When this happens, I'm getting the following OutOfMemoryException:

```
DateTime:2014-08-04 12:55:26,035 Thread ID:[1] Log Level:ERROR Logger Property:OS_fileParser.Program property:[(null)] - Message:System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.ExpandByABlock(Int32 minBlockCharCount)
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char* value, Int32 valueCount)
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char[] value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 charCount)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
   at OS_fileParser.MyProgram.FormatXmlFile(String inFile) in D:\Test\myProgram.cs:line 530
   at OS_fileParser.MyProgram.Run() in D:\Test\myProgram.cs:line 336
```

Line 530 contains `content = Regex.Replace(content, pattern, "");`, while line 336 calls a method with the following body:

```cs
const string pattern = @"[^\x20-\x7E]";

string content;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(inFile))
{
    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
}

content = Regex.Replace(content, pattern, "");

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(inFile + ".NonAsciiChars"))
{
    writer.Write(content);
    writer.Close();
}

using (var myXmlReader = XmlReader.Create(inFile + ".NonAsciiChars", myXmlReaderSettings))
{
    try
    {
        while (myXmlReader.Read())
        {
        }
    }
    catch (XmlException ex)
    {
        Logger.Error("Validation error: " + ex);
    }
}
```

How can I improve the memory footprint of my code?

Comment: Original question, cross-posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121754/is-there-any-better-way-to-replace-non-ascii-chars-in-c-sharp

Comment: so this works for smaller files, but is not efficient on larger files?

Comment: @Malachi, yes, you are right, tested 10 files (less then 50MB) all working fine, but when I try to process the 2GB file, it went into OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: Voting to reopen: this code is working, but is inefficient. Optimisation questions are on-topic for Code Review. (Incidentally, I retracted my Close Vote but it claimed I had no outstanding votes on the question... bug?)

Comment: @Schism, it was probably already reopened when you tried to retract your vote

Comment: Have you tried simply running this in a 64-bit mode?

Comment: @svick, no I didn't, because I am using 32 bit machine ONLY.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@svick's approach is the right one, given these considerations

> - the input file can be as big as 4 GB
> - the data may all be on two lines

However I would suggest that regular expressions are the wrong tool for the job, and you will find it faster to use a `StreamReader` with a specified encoding.

There is a method [`Encoding.GetEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/89856k4b(v=vs.110).aspx) that does the following:

> Returns the encoding associated with the specified code page name.
>   Parameters specify an error handler for characters that cannot be
>   encoded and byte sequences that cannot be decoded.

There is also a [`DecoderReplacementFallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.text.decoderreplacementfallback(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

> Provides a failure-handling mechanism, called a fallback, for an
>   encoded input byte sequence that cannot be converted to an output
>   character. The fallback emits a user-specified replacement string
>   instead of a decoded input byte sequence.

Putting that all together would look like this:

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("us-ascii", new EncoderExceptionFallback(), new DecoderReplacementFallback(string.Empty));
const int BufferSize = 4096;
using (var reader = new StreamReader("in.txt", encoding))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("out.txt", false, new UTF8Encoding(false), BufferSize))
{
    var buffer = new char[BufferSize];
    int read;
    while ((read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, BufferSize)) != 0)
    {
        writer.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Now that use of `UTF8Encoding` might look like a mistake, but according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If you are planning to use an ASCII encoding (`ASCIIEncoding`), choose
>   `UTF8Encoding` instead. The two encodings are identical for the ASCII
>   character set, but `UTF8Encoding` has the following advantages:
>
> - It has been tuned to be as fast as possible and should be faster than
>     any other encoding. Even for content that is entirely ASCII,
>     operations performed with `UTF8Encoding` are faster than operations
>     performed with `ASCIIEncoding`.

We use the constructor so that it doesn't emit a byte order mark, unlike `Encoding.UTF8`.

---

I wrote the code above based on your description "remove non-ASCII characters in a text file", but now realise your requirements are more specific: to remove characters outside the range 32-126. It can be easily modified to support that requirement:

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("us-ascii", new EncoderExceptionFallback(), new DecoderReplacementFallback(string.Empty));
const int BufferSize = 4096;
using (var reader = new StreamReader("in.txt", encoding))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("out.txt", false, new UTF8Encoding(false), BufferSize))
{
    var buffer = new char[BufferSize];
    var chars = new char[BufferSize];
    int read;
    while ((read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, BufferSize)) != 0)
    {
        var j = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < read; i++)
        {
            char c = buffer[i];
            if (c >= 32 && c <= 126)
            {
                chars[j++] = c;
            }
        }

        writer.Write(chars, 0, j);
    }
}
```

#### Timing

I ran tests on a 4GB file with random content, generated by [Dummy File Creator](http://www.mynikko.com/dummy/).

```
$ time tr -cd '\40-\176' < in.txt > out.txt

real    0m52.034s
user    0m24.897s
sys     0m22.791s

$ time ./AsciiCopy.exe in.txt out.txt

real    1m9.140s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.031s

$ time ./AsciiCopyRegex.exe in.txt out.txt

real    17m59.618s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.016s
```

Comment: thanks mjolka, on my VM it tooks 6 Mins to process 3.39 GB file. Amazing!!!, when I open by EmEditor Pro 32 Bit 12.0.11 I found TAB still inside the output file which is inside ASCII Table but I dont need it. is there any way to remove also? I want ASCII Dec32 to Dec 126 ONLY. thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3724711 I've updated the post.

Comment: thanks a lot, the speed also amazing, on my VM it tooks 7 mins only, I believe in server it will be fantastic. thanks a lot. this is a really good solution. I will change to 'if ((c >= 32 && c <= 126) || c == 10 || c == 13)' to support Line Feed and Carriage Return also, which I forgot to mentioned. thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You need to use the two `Stream`s as, well, streams: read a manageable part of the input, transform it, write it to the output and repeat.

```
int bufferSize = 4096; // or whatever

char[] characters = new char[bufferSize];

using (var reader = new StreamReader(inFile))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(inFile + ".NonAsciiChars"))
{
    while (true)
    {
        int read = reader.Read(characters, 0, characters.Length);

        if (read == 0)
            break;

        var replaced = Regex.Replace(new string(characters), pattern, string.Empty);

        writer.Write(replaced);
    }
}
```

Some notes about this code:

1. Notice the missing `Close()` calls: the whole point of `using` is safe closing of streams, and similar resources, so you don't need to close them twice.
2. This code (just like the original) creates a lot of garbage to be collected by the GC. Since your regex is actually very simple, it might be better to manually work directly with `char[]`s.
3. I used `string.Empty` instead of `""`. This makes it very clear that empty string was actually intended and it's not just “I started writing string and then forgot about it” bug.

Comment: thanks svick, Seems it works, on my VM it tooks 18 Mins to process 3.39 GB file. only thing is when I use EmEditor Pro 32 Bit 12.0.11 to open the Output .NonAsciiChars file I am getting "Too many characters in a single line. Out of memory."  not sure why... but file size did changed, seems it's good.

Answer (score 2):

okay first of all, you need to use buffered stream to read data from the file, there is no need to write data once in file as it might hung altogether.

so I would suggest that read the file line by line , parse it and then write to file.

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(infile, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(fileStream))
    {
        using (var writer = File.AppendText(infile + ".NonAsciiChars"))
        {
            using (var stremReader = new StreamReader(bufferedStream))
            {
                string inputContent;
                while ((inputContent = stremReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string content = Regex.Replace(inputContent, pattern, "");
                    writer.WriteLine(content); //you can replace with write too if you want
                }
            }
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. some time the file coming in ONE line only, when i use stremReader.ReadLine() same error popup at Regex.Replace(inputContent, pattern, "");

Comment: that is why I am reading from buffered stream which is actually a chunk of data which fixed size , so you should not get any error

Comment: @paritosh That's not what `BufferedStream` does. When you ask for a line, you get a line, not something smaller.

Comment: You are right and I apologise

Comment: thanks alot, it works, when i run 3 GB file every min can process 0.05 GB  the program still running but till now already 1.17 GB finished, not more outofmemory cames, thank you so much +1

Comment: "there is zero benefit from wrapping a BufferedStream around a FileStream" --http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/04/15/114329.aspx

Comment: This is quite old blog

Comment: @paritosh the reason your code doesn't throw an OOM exception is because it's using `ReadLine` instead of `ReadToEnd` -- it has nothing to do with `BufferedStream`. As the file can be two lines and 4GB, you're still reading a 2GB string into memory and running a regex over it, which is very inefficient in terms of both memory and speed.